# Unable to get documents when I use ES6 in my node js

Tags: mongodb, ecmascript-6, mean-stack

I'm working on MEAN stack to create some web services.
I thought of using ES6 for synchronizing mongodb find operations.
Here is the code(UserService):

```
var Todo = require('../models/user.js');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/abc');
var Users = db.model('User');


function *myGenerator() {
   return yield Todo.find({});//Throwing Undefined function Todo.find
   //return yield Users.find({}); //DOes not returns documents but returns a json object which has full mongodb database details
}

function getDocs(){
   var iterator = myGenerator();
   var firstYield = iterator.next();
}
```

`return yield Todo.find({})` is throwing exception `Undefined function Todo.find`

`return yield Users.find({});` does not return documents but returns a JSON object which has full mongodb database details

`return yield Users.find({}).exec()` returns following output

```
{ value:
Promise {
emitter:
EventEmitter {
domain: null,
_events: {},
_eventsCount: 0,
_maxListeners: undefined },
emitted: {},
ended: false },
done: false }
```

PS: I used `--harmony` node js option as well.

Could you please help me to get User rows/documents?

Comment: Why are you `yield`ing promises? Nothing in your `getDocs` function does anything actually useful with it. Sounds like you don't want to use generators but rather `async`/`await` syntax!

Answer (score 1):

`Todo.find({});` returns a `Query` object. You must call `exec` function on that object to execute the query. **e.g.**

```
Todo.find({}).exec(function (error, docs) {
    if (error) {
        // handle
    }

    if (docs) {
        // yeah !!!
    }
})
```

Also `mongoose` database connection is asynchronous. So any queries made before the connection is established obviously wont work. Here's a working example..

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = Promise;

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (error) => {

  if (error) {
    throw error
  }

  console.log('DB Connected');

  var Todo = require('./models/user.js');

  var Users = db.model('User');


  function *myGenerator() {
    yield Todo.find({}); // Returns a Query object
    //yield Users.find({}); // Returns a Query object
  }

  function getDocs(){
    var iterator = myGenerator();
    var firstYield = iterator.next();

    // firstYield is a `Query` object

    firstYield.value.exec((error, users) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      console.log(users);
    })
  }

  getDocs();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`var Todo = requires('models/user.js');` produces `ReferenceError: requires is not defined`
should be `var Todo = require('models/user.js');`

maybe even
`var Todo = require('./models/user.js');` because `'models/user.js'` is relative to the `node_modules` directory

`return yield Todo.find({});`
should be `yield Todo.find({});`

As far as I can see **this** code will throw an Exception.
Please provide the **actual code** and some more info like what version of `node.js` you are currently running ?

p.S I wrote this in the answers section because I have yet to earned the comment everywhere priveledge

Comment: Thank you very much sgiant! I updated my post. Even no effect if I remove return.

Comment: Hi, My intention is to convert union selects of mysql to mongodb query. Also the selects vary in number(i.e. N no.of selects based on inputs). So I thought of executing one by one find()s sequentially and club the results. Tried above code with generators and co etc, but no results. I could manage it by writing a recursive function where each find function concatenates the results and calls itself for next find. Sorry to say that I did not try your answer to indicate it as accepted answer. Thanks for your help! but surely its +1.